# DIVs overlapping. Need to move it over so they don't

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically what the title says. Though the spacing needs to be the same on any resoulution. I tried to do it with css but on different resolutions it moves around a bit. It dosn't matter how you do it (javascript, css, html), as long as it works.

You can view the site that im having issues on [here](http://bindmind.net/dev/).

Comment: you mean the `fatal error check code` piece?

Comment: looks good on Chrome?  What browser are you using?  And where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong when using IE 9 either - at least nothing obvious.

Comment: It depends on the resolution you use. Fixed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is the **Fatal Error. Check Code.** bit at the top, then do this

Change

```
#newscontent {
top: 4px;
left: 14%;
position: fixed;
}
```

to

```
#newscontent {
top: 4px;
left: 18%;  //CHANGE HERE
position: fixed;
}
```

This will keep the text from overlapping the **Latest News** bit, at least until the page shrinks smaller than the BB.

Even better would be to make `#newscontent` a `span` and place it inside the `#news div`, so there would be no overlapping or separation no matter what the screen size.

Comment: Yes but on different resoultions it will have a bigger gap.

Comment: Correct @Adam543i.  See the last line of my answer (which I just added). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

only #topbar should be positioned absolute (if needed), child divs can have float left and margin/padding right

Comment: #serverstats {
    float: left;
    font: bold 120% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}#news {
    float: left;
    font: bold 120% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}#newscontent {
    float: left;    
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

Answer (score 0):

OK, so bottom line is you don't want to solve this using absolute or fixed positioning with left-offset percentages.  This approach will fail depending on screen resolution and length of text.  A better approach is to float the items, which will allow them to "push" the next element to the right, if need be.  Try this:

First, remove all your CSS for your `#serverstats`, `#news`, and `#newscontent` selectors.

Second, on all three of those divs, add a `menu-item` class:

```
<div id="serverstats" class="menu-item">...</div>
<div id="news" class="menu-item">...</div>
<div id="newscontent" class="menu-item">...</div>
```

Third, add the following CSS to your style sheet:

```
.menu-item {
    float: left;
    font: bold 120% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```